# #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 1 | Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

Hey guys I/m hoping that somebody here can give me a helping hand...

I'm trying to import a DB for my wordpress site but I'm getting errors.

Here is the error I'm getting!

> -- -- Dumping data for table `wp_comments` -- INSERT INTO `wp_comments` (`comment_ID`, `comment_post_ID`, `comment_author`, `comment_author_email`, `comment_author_url`, `comment_author_IP`, `comment_date`, `comment_date_gmt`, `comment_content`, `comment_karma`, `comment_approved`, `comment_agent`, `comment_type`, `comment_parent`, `user_id`) VALUES (1, 1, 'Mr WordPress', '', 'http://wordpress.org/', '', '2013-02-19 11:30:17', '2013-02-19 11:30:17', 'Hi, this is a comment.\nTo delete a comment, just log in and view the post's comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.', 0, '1', '', '', 0, 0), (2, 81, 'admin', 'support@hpb.com', '', '223.255.245.41', '2013-02-28 13:34:06', '2013-02-28 13:34:06', 'This is test comment...', 0, '1', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0', '', 0, 1), (3, 75, 'admin', 'support@hpb.com', '', '223.255.245.41', '2013-02-28 13:34:21', '2013-02-28 13:34:21', 'This is test comment...', 0, '[...]

Comment: You already have a comment in the database with `comment_ID` == 1. When you try to insert another one you get an error. It is supposed to work that way. I imagine you are trying to do the import/migration incorrectly but based on the limited information provided I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the database you're importing to already has a comment in the database with an ID of 1 and that table has a duplicate id restriction.  You can either go through and change all of the IDs of the entries in the dump file or you can probably truncate your current comments table and see if it will let you import it then.